# I'm back, normal service to resume shortly

Tags: discussion

As several of you know, I've been away for the past ~6 months on the Appalachian Trail (where I generally did not have access to the internet, as you might expect). I've been back since the 06th of October and am now getting back into my former duties as moderator. This means if you have any questions or concerns, you're welcome to send them my way again if needed.

So, my question for you is this: I haven't been around since the March Site Self-Evaluation; what's been happening since I've been away? How is the community doing? I can tell that I have a lot of catching up to do!